# Can connecting 100K concurrent users in socket.io node.js is possible

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am new to socket.io in nodejs . i had a doubt how many concurrent connection can i connect with my nodejs app and is it possible to connect 100K user concurrently . my code is working fine

my code

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('joinroom', ({ username, room }) => {
        const user = userjoin(socket.id, username, room);
        socket.join(user.room);
        socket.emit('message', formatmessage('bot', 'Welcoming by bot'));
        socket.broadcast.to(user.room).emit('message',formatmessage(' bot',`${user.name} just joined`));
    });
    socket.on('chatMessage', (msg) => {
        const user = getCurrntuser(socket.id);
        io.to(user.room).emit('message',formatmessage(user.name,msg));
    });
     socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
        const user = userLeave(socket.id);
        if (user) {
            io.to(user.room).emit('message',formatmessage('bot',`${user.name} just now disconnected`));       
        }        
    });
});
```

Anyone had idea how any connection is possible at same time !
thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The question is hard to answer because it depends on the machine that runs the code and the intensity of the communication.

But I would like to address that the question should be more akin to "How to support a large number of clients using NodeJS" because today it's 100k tomorrow 10k or 1M.

You should look into **microservice architected** and **scaling solutions**. The basic gist is you need the ability to add more **replicas** of the same stateless service when you need to support more users/connections. This can be achieved when using a [load balancer](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/) and stateless microservice.

I know this isn't a direct answer to the question but I hope it will put you on the right path to solve the issue.

Comment: if i rent a powerful machine then i need to load balance it ?

Comment: With JS you should. Due to JS being single-threaded Its always a good practice to replicate it. With outer programming languages, you would need to scale up the thread pool (but replicating them works as well).

Answer (score 0):

Microservices architecture solves scalability problems like these. These are problems you would have not only in NodeJS but in other languages as well. I believe that the solution in your case is to work with a load balancer scaling your service. take a look at https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/

Comment: i don't what to scale my project , is it fine to run this application in one server (with high CPU and RAM)?

Comment: You can scale your project by making multiple instances on the same server or on different servers. This is needed in single-threaded languages like NodeJS. Read about PM2 there (answer link) that will better understand how it works